# Programmatically add VMware ESX host to vCenter during kickstart

Tags: vmware, esx

I'd like to have my ESX hosts add themselves to vCenter during the kickstart process (or in a script that runs after the first boot).

I can't find a method for doing this; is there one?

Answer (score 0):

There are methods in the API to add hosts: one for [standalone hosts](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vim.Folder.html#addStandaloneHost), and one for [hosts in a cluster](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vim.ClusterComputeResource.html#addHost).

I'm not sure what scripting tools you have available during the kickstart process, but I recommend using one of VMware's scripting wrappers: the [PowerCLI](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/vsphere/automationtools/powercli) for powershell, for instance. There are SDKs available in .Net and Perl, among others. See [here for more API information](http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/sdk_pubs.html).